# How do you run Spring Cloud Data Flow behind a proxy

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run Spring Cloud Data Flow behind a proxy.

I have added proxy configuration to maven as well as passing it in as a parameter, but the results are the same.

I am getting these errors

Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:file-source-kafka-10:jar:metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE from/to springRepo (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot): Connection refused (Connection refused)

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:file-source-kafka-10:jar:metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE from/to springRepo (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot): Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444) ~[aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar!/:na]
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246) ~[aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar!/:na]
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifacts(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:302) ~[aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.resource.maven.MavenArtifactResolver.resolve(MavenArtifactResolver.java:294) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-resource-maven-1.3.0.M2.jar!/:1.3.0.M2]
        ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:file-source-kafka-10:jar:metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE from/to springRepo (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot): Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43) ~[aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar!/:na]
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355) ~[aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar!/:na]
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67) ~[aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar!/:na]
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581) ~[aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar!/:na]
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249) ~[aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar!/:na]
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520) ~[aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar!/:na]
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421) ~[aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar!/:na]
        ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure proxy settings for the maven repository. The configuration properties are documented in the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-maven-configuration) with a sample.